# Select values from multiple tables - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have the following Database structure:

Table `users` contains :  `email, name`

table `connections` contains  :`followingemail, followedemail, isfollowedaccept`

table `locations` contains: `location, email`.

I Want to get the the `name` and the the `location` of the my friend when:  I have the value of my Email which is `followingemail` and I have the value of my friend's email which is  `followedemail`.

It should retrieve the data  only if I have a row in `connctions` table that contains my email as`followingemail`  and my friend's email as `followedemail` and also  `isfollowedaccept` is true.

My question is how can I write that query?

I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @madalinivascu You write, sorry

Comment: you need to join these tables

Comment: @madalinivascu Is there any other way to so it?

Comment: i think with a select is possibile

Comment: before posting this query you should have tried some query and posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.name, l.location
from connections C
join users U on U.followedemail =  C.email
join location l on l.email =  C.email 
where C.followingemail = (your email)
and   U.followedemail = (your friend's email)
and U.isfollowedaccept = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `users` and `locations` 2 times each for getting the data, something as

```
select
u1.name as following_name,
u2.name as followed_name,
l1.location as following_location,
l2.location as followed_location
from connections c
join users u1 on u1.email = c.followingemail
join users u2 on u2.email = c.followedemail
join locations l1 on l1.email = c.followingemail
join locations l2 on l2.email = c.followedemail
where 
c.followingemail = '{your email}' 
and c.followedemail = '{friends email}'
and c. isfollowedaccept = 'true'
```